# Starred message from ignored users should not show up

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, ignored-users

When you ignore a user, you don't want to read their posts.

However, if messages by such users get starred, they do show up in the sidebar list of starred messages even though you ignore them.

Comment: This is important really, as users are starring messages just to show me the message of the ignored user, they said it clearly in chat. Can someone from SE please pay attention to this.

Comment: Ignored messages also appear in transcripts.

Comment: @Raphael this is different, IMO they should still appear in transcripts.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd For some purposes yes (e.g. moderation), but not for others (read a conversation without the "spam"). Maybe a switch would be nice?

Comment: @Raphael nah, the purpose of ignoring a user, as I see it, is to not see this in the room itself. Outside the room, well, it doesn't really matter. (for me)